# While running SSH task in CD pipeline of azure devops, getting permission denied and too many authentications failure error

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

While trying to perform deployment using azure DevOps release pipeline on Linux server, I am getting below error:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Received disconnect from port 22:2: Too many authentication failures.
Disconnected from port 22.
```

For resolving this issue, I have generated the public and private keys for Linux server user using below command:
`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

After this I have added public key under azure DevOps user settings. Even after following above steps, I am still getting authentication failure error.

Can anyone please guide me on what needs to be done?